# My channel handles are not appearing

Tags: animation, bones, keyframes, graph-editor

I'm trying to edit my ball's animation using the graph editor. However, when I click a keyframe, the handles do not appear. Also, does the format of my graph look correct? Thanks

Link: https://we.tl/t-HZMQm5EpOb

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a *Constant* interpolation, it makes a square graph, there is no handle for this interpolation, if you want handles you need to switch to a *Bezier* interpolation (press <kbd>T</kbd> > *Interpolation > Bezier*)

Comment: Thanks moonboots! :)